# Linq, selecting two records from one table based on 2 different ID's

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to create a statement in where i start out with an ID to select an object in table1, then take 2 new ids from that object and using them to look up 2 different objects in table2.
My goal is to end up with an anonymous object that has the object from table1 and the 2 objects from table2 i.e. `(table1.object, table2.object1, table2.object2)`.

I don't know if this can be done in a single statement or not.

So far I got this, but it only gives me `table1.object` and `table2.object1`, and not `table2.object2`:

```
db.Person.Where(x => x.Id == myId)
      .SelectMany(p => db.OtherPerson
        .Where(o=> p.OhterP1_Id1 == o.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (p, o) => new {pers = p, otherP = o})
```

Comment: What if there were more than two objects in table2 for the object from table1? Or just one?

Comment: There can only be 2 objects in table2 for the object in table1, the Id is unique

Comment: So... your object has `OhterP1_Id1` and `OhterP1_Id2`?

Comment: Yes, the object has two id's that i need to lookup in table 2 and get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
var result = db.Person.Where(x => x.Id == myId)
.Select(p => new {
pers = p,
otherP1 = db.OtherPerson.SingleOrDefault(o => p.OhterP1_Id1 == o.Id),
otherP2 = db.OtherPerson.SingleOrDefault(o => p.OhterP1_Id2 == o.Id)
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Only had to change to "FirstOrDefault()" to get it to work

Comment: @user7324523 `FirstOrDefault()` means there is more than one such an object and you use any of them. Are you sure `FirstOrDefault()` is what you want?

Comment: The SingleOrDefault() throws a "Not Supported" exception as i have not used ToList yet.

Comment: @K.M Yes, you are right, `SIngleOrDefault()` is not supported in Entity Framework 3.5, but it works in EF 4.0.